# bootstrap modal displays twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I have a users table with a button that shows a modal containing info about the user.

So I will have 10 rows, each with its own button, the first time I press a button, it will display a modal (let's call this modal A) containing the info for the user and work normally.

When I click on a button for another user it will display modal A then on top it will display the correct modal (modal B) when I close this modal, modal A is no longer on screen but the backdrop will still be visible.

I'm using laravel 5.5 with bootstrap 3 here is the code for the modal load.

Javascript

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
    var button = $(this)
    var employee_id = button.data('id')
    var url = "/something/else/" + employee_id;
    $('.modal-container').load(url,function(result){
         $('#display').modal({show:true});
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-id="{{ $simething->id }}" href="#display" id="modal_link">Show Modal</a>
```

This is the complete code

```
<table id="table" class="table" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="grid">
     <thead>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>First Name</th>
         <th>Last Name</th>
         <th>Events</th>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     @foreach ($empleados as $empleado)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $simething->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $simething->fname }}</td>
            <td>{{ $simething->lname }}</td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-id="{{ $simething->id }}" href="#display" id="modal_link">Show Modal</a>
                <div class="modal-container"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
     @endforeach
 </tbody>
```

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){

                $(".btn").on('click', function(e){
                    var button = $(this); // Button that triggered the modal
                    var employee_id = button.data('id'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
                    var url = "/somethin/else/" + employee_id;
                    $('.modal-container').load(url,function(){
                        $('#display').modal('show');
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: are you runing this javascript code inside a loop? please put more code to a better view

Comment: How many components with class `modal-container` are there on the page ?

Comment: @DioneiMiodutzki, nope, im not running the script in a loop, its inside a `$(document).ready(function(){})`

Comment: @Titus, I have one component with class `modal-container` per button, so it's more than one

Comment: In that case, you should use something like `$(this).parents("tr").find('.modal-container')` and multiple elements with class name `modal-container` implies multiple elements with the same ID (`display`), if that is the case, use a class name instead and call `.modal({show:true})` on the modal corresponding to the pressed button.

Comment: multiple issues here i think. data-toggle='modal' is meant for launching the modal automatically by the href="#display" id given.  So you are launching it via the built in code, but also loading one yourself and displaying it using the $('#display').modal(...) code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are launching the modal twice every time, which after a few clicks is probably stacking up and causing the issues you're seeing.  Try changing your html to not auto launch a modal, like so:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary modal-btn" data-id="{{ $simething->id }}" href="#/" id="modal_link">Show Modal</a>
```

Also, you shouldnt use the ".btn" as the way you select the button, as many buttons on your page may have that boostrap class. I would give it a unique class that you only want to target this modal with, or an ID if its for only one button per click event.  Change your javascript to this:

```
$(".modal-btn").click(function(){
    var button = $(this)
    var employee_id = button.data('id')
    var url = "/something/else/" + employee_id;
    $('.modal-container').load(url,function(result){
         $('#display').modal({show:true});
    });
});
```